# trying to figure out why my code thinks the correct word is wrong the second time i enter into the text box

Tags: python, spell-checking, pyspellchecker

```
# i have already imported all necessary libraries and it is randomly choosing a word
word_list = r.get_random_word()
chosen_one = word_list
input_rect = pygame.Rect(200, 200, 140, 32)
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ""
user_words = ""
###
counter_text = 0
list_of_words = []


###
#check_spelling = spell.unknown(word_list)

#print(check_spelling)

while running:
    # poll for events
    # pygame.QUIT event means the user clicked X to close your window
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if input_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                active = True
            else:
                active = False
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
  
            # get the correct word to append to user words and change user text back to empty
           

            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:

                # This array takes the current user_input and stores in array
                list_of_words.append(user_text)

                # This loop takes the word in the array and checks if it is correct
                for word in list_of_words:

                    # This actually checks if it is correct by comparing original and newly corrected word
                    user_words = spell.correction(word)

                    # If the word is actually correct, run etc.
                    if word == user_words:
                        
                        # split the word into letters for single-use

                        # all possible words exist in chose_one
                  
                        letter_array = [] # ["a", "p", "p", "l", "e"]
                        for i in chosen_one:
                            letter_array.append(i)
                    
                        # If the word when user types enter, is not in the word, automatically say wrong letters in text
                        for j in range(len(word)):
                        
                            # go through each letter and compare in the array
                            if word[j] in letter_array:
                                if j == (len(word) - 1):

                                    # go through each letter and check if the last letter equals the current letter
                                    word += user_words
                                    user_text = ""
                                    counter_text += 1
                                
                            else:
                                print(j, word, letter_array)
                                user_text = "That's not a letter in the word, try again."
                                break

                    else:
                        
                        user_text = "That's not a word, try again."
```

I was trying to make a game that takes a random word for example "mountains" and you make as many word as you can out of that one word with only those letters for example here with "mountains" you could make "tin" "stain" "mount" "tan" etc. and every time you get a word correct you add 1 to the counter box if the letters aren't in the word say so and if its not a word say so the current issue is it only correctly does that once and I don't know why

Comment: Why do you go through all of `list_of_words` every time? Why not just check the word the user just typed?

Comment: @Barmar Because I want to wait for them to press enter before checking which is what K_return does

Comment: When they press enter, you add the current word to `list_of_words`, then loop over that list. But the previous time they pressed enter you already checked the other words. There's no need to check them again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your algorithm for checking if the entered word is inside the random word. A simple way to do this is to sort the letters of the random word, sort the letters of the entered word, then check if one is a substring of the other.